# BasicDataSource to DataSource

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-camel, datasource

I am trying to use camels sql: and have googled myself into this:

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
import org.apache.camel.impl.{SimpleRegistry, DefaultCamelContext}

object CamelApplication {
  val jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://host:3306"
  val user = "test"
  val password = "secret"
  val driverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

  // code to create data source here
  val ds = new BasicDataSource

  ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl)
  ds.setUsername(user)
  ds.setPassword(password)
  ds.setDriverClassName(driverClass)

  val registry = new SimpleRegistry
  registry.put("dataSource", ds)

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry)

    context.setUseMDCLogging(true)
    context.addRoutes(new DlrToDb)
    context.start()
    Thread.currentThread.join()
  }
}
```

and my DlrToDb route is this:

```
import org.apache.camel.scala.dsl.builder.RouteBuilder

class DlrToDb extends RouteBuilder{

  """netty:tcp://localhost:12000?textline=true""" ==> {
    id("DlrToDb")
    log("sql insert coming up")
    to("sql:insert into camel_test (msgid, dlr_body) VALUES ('some_id','test')")
  }
}
```

i.e. when I telnet to localhost and press enter I would like some data to be added in my database. However it is a BasicDataSource and not a DataSource so I get an error:

```
Failed to create route DlrToDb .....
....  due to: Property 'dataSource' is required
```

Do I need to change/convert from the BasicDatasource, or do I need to do something to the registry to make it work?

Comment: The error talks about a missing property with name `dataSource`, not about the class name (a `BasicDataSource` IS-A `DataSource`); I also wonder if `registry.put("dataSource", ds.getConnection)` shouldn't be `registry.put("dataSource", ds)`

Comment: the .getConnection was an error, you're right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append query option "dataSource" to the URI:

```
....
to("sql:insert into camel_test (msgid, dlr_body) VALUES ('some_id','test')?dataSource=dataSource")
....
```